# Multiple makers and type conversion

Tags: c++

```
Vector<Medicine*>* Controller::sortByStockAsc(){
    Vector<Medicine*>* all =repo->getAll();
    qsort(all, all->getSize(),sizeof(Medicine*), (comparefunction) compareNA);
    return all;
}
```

So,I have the function above which should sort an array of objects.I get the error

```
cannot convert 'Vector<Medicine*>' to 'Vector<Medicine*>*' in initialization
```

But if I write it as `Vector<Medicine*> all =repo->getAll();`  I get a bunch of new errors for the 3rd line(which aren't there if I have the previous error on the 2nd line):

```
Multiple markers at this line
    - Method 'getSize' could not be resolved
    - Invalid arguments ' Candidates are: void qsort(void *, unsigned int, unsigned int, int (*)(const void *, const 
     void *)) '
    - base operand of '->' has non-pointer type 'Vector<Medicine*>'
```

What's wrong with this and how can I fix it?

Comment: what does `repo->getAll()` return?

Comment: So many things are wrong, where do I even start? You have a function that sounds like an instruction to do something, but then returns something. You use qsort. You cast a function pointer. You don't understand the difference between a pointer, a reference and a value. You have a vector of pointers, and you return one too (or even a pointer to a vector of pointers), which is completely confusing from an ownership perspective. Basically, the problem is that you don't know C++. To fix it, I suggest reading a good book.

Comment: @Named all the objects of type Vector<Medicine*>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
Vector<Medicine*> Controller::getMedicinesSortedByStockAsc() {
    Vector<Medicine*> all = repo->getAll();
    std::sort(all.begin(), all.end(), compareNA);
    return all;
}
```

Notes:

- You didn't provide a definition of `Vector` so I assume it is STL-compatible.  Judging by the rest of the code this may be an incorrect assumption.
- You didn't provide a description of `compareNA` but I've chosen to assume that it can be made compatible with STL-style algorithms.

Comment: `class Vector
{
private:
 T* Elems;
 int Size;
 int Capacity;`
...+constructor,destructor,getters.

Comment: `int compareNA(const Medicine* e1, const Medicine* e2){
 int q1 = (*(Medicine **) e1)->getStock();
 int q2 = (*(Medicine **) e2)->getStock();

 if (q1 < q2){
    return -1;
   }
 else{
  if (q1>q2){
   return 1;
  }
  return 0;
 }
}`

Comment: I've tryed your version but I get this error:
_Multiple markers at this line
 - Invalid arguments ' Candidates are: void sort(#0, #0) void sort(#0, 
  #0, #1) '
 - Method 'begin' could not be resolved
 - Method 'end' could not be resolved_