# Qsort dilemma in C++

Tags: c++, qsort

```
Vector<Medicine*>* Controller::sortByStockAsc(){
        Vector<Medicine*>* all =repo->getAll();
        qsort(all, all->getNrMed(),sizeof(Medicine*), (comparefunction) compareNA);
        return all;}
```

I have the above code and my qsort has some problems. `Vector<Medicine*>*` is a pointer to an array of pointers which I need to sort out. `getAll()` returns a `Vector <Medicine*>*`.
One of the problems is that in `qsort()` my `getNrMed()` isn't found although I specified the module where this function is defined. The function looks like:

```
int MedRepository::getNrMed(){
    return MedList->getSize();
}
```

and returns a `int`. What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What is `Vector`? It seems very wrong that you're using `qsort`.

Comment: `class Vector
{
private:
 T* Elems;
 int Size;
 int Capacity;`
+ constructors,destructors and getters

Comment: You might want to describe what "my qsort has some problems" means, is it depressive because it can't pay its mortgage? Use `std::sort()`, because `qsort()` uses `memcpy()` to swap objects, which isn't always suitable for C++ objects.

Comment: @doomster tryed it like `std::sort(*all.begin(), all.end(), compareNA);` but I get 'Method begin and end could not be rezolved' together with  'Invalid arguments'

Comment: Try `all->begin()` or `(*all).begin()`. That said, guessing code, unspecified error messages ("rezolved"?), still not all of the code - you're not helping others to help you. Another warning: the functions required for C's qsort() and C++'s std::sort() are different and _not_ compatible!

Comment: Wait, is it a home-made `Vector`?

Comment: @Joker_vD What do you mean by home-made?

Comment: He means not `std::vector`.

Comment: No,my `Vector` is a defined class based on a template.

Comment: I know what you mean, but to be clear `std::vector` is also a class based on a template. It just happens to ship with your compiler, but it's not treated special in any particular way.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Multiple makers and type conversion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16416841/multiple-makers-and-type-conversion)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`qsort` doesn't take a `Vector<T>*`. It takes a pointer to the first element of the vector.

`getNrMed` is not a method of `Vector<T>`, it's a method of `MedRepository` which is seen nowhere else in this snippet.

The fact that you need to put a cast on `compareNA` is the sign of a serious problem. It's almost *never* safe to cast a function pointer. You need to make it compile without a cast.

Undoubtedly, given the code quality here, there are additional issues--this is just what can be diagnosed given the limited amount of code you presented.

Comment: how can I make it compile without a cast?What parts of code you think I should show beside the upper fragments?

Comment: To make it compile without cast, just change the function prototype to the one expected by `qsort()`. The first thing inside that comparison function is to convert the void pointers back to typed pointers. Do yourself the favor and try to use this to sort a simple array of integers, i.e. create a separate test project to get familiar with this.

Comment: Man, you are out of your depth. You appear to be gainfully employed, can you go to another engineer and ask for help in person? Trying to debug this over SO is going to be a nightmare when you don't know what you are doing.

Comment: uhm,I'm not an employee,I'm a student curently learning c++ for a couple weeks and this code is a part of a project I've been assigned to make.

Comment: Do you have any sort of assistance, like a professor or TA or something? Or are you just flying blind?

Comment: I could ask a professor via mail but I don't know if I'll get an answer,we have a 2 week break.